# Problems with PHP Output Buffer Flush

Tags: php, buffer, output-buffering

I have a PHP script which takes a while to process and I wanted to get the site to display it's progress while it is running.

I have been having problems displaying the contents of the output buffer while a PHP code is running.  I have been trying the use of `ob_implicit_flush(true)`, `ob_end_flush()` and `ob_flush()` with no success.

After looking for a fair bit at the PHP manual on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/) I have come across a comment by Lee saying

> As of August 2012, all browsers seem to show an all-or-nothing
>   approach to buffering. In other words, while php is operating, no
>   content can be shown.
>
> In particular this means that the following workarounds listed further
>   down here are ineffective:
>
> 1) ob_flush (),  flush () in any combination with other output
>   buffering functions;
>
> 2) changes to php.ini involving setting output_buffer and/or
>   zlib.output_compression to 0 or Off;
>
> 3) setting Apache variables such as "no-gzip" either through
>   apache_setenv () or through entries in .htaccess.
>
> So, until browsers begin to show buffered content again, the tips
>   listed here are moot.

[see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

If he is correct, is there an alternative I can use to display the progress of the script running?

**[edit]**

Looks like Lee could be right. I have been doing some testing and here is an example of the problem

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
   echo $i.'<br>';
   sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Should display 0 to 4 with a second in between. What actually happens is that the site waits 5 seconds then displays 0 to 4 immediately. It is waiting for the script to complete then displays everything in one go.

I have had `output_buffering = Off` in my php.ini file and tried setting it to 1 and 4096 (4096 being 4KB) and it still does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the buffer size and make an "empty" dummy of that size, for example...

```
$flushdummy="";
for ($i=0; $i<700; $i++) { $flushdummy=$flushdummy."      "; }
$flushdummy=$flushdummy."\n";
```

then, when output is desired, add the dummy to the output, plus the flush:

```
echo "here I am<br />", $flushdummy;
flush();
@ob_flush();
```